# SOAP Response to Dataset

Tags: c#, winforms, soap, dataset

I'm trying to convert the response I'm getting from Web Service into a DataSet so I can bind it to a GridView.

The response is already serialized.

Comment: please leave tags like " C# Winforms" out of your title. They belong in the tags - only.

Comment: What is the format of the XML? You can't convert arbitrary XML to a DataSet, but if it's not arbitrary, there may be a chance.

Answer (score 0):

It need not be only a DataSet to bind to GridView. You can bind a list as well. If you're receiving a collection of records from the SOAP request, try binding it directly GridView and it will work.